# Left join query using Linq2Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have 3 tables called Users, Groups and UserGroups.
UserGroups is the many 2 many join table.

I want to write a linq statement that gets me only those groups
that DO NOT have a UserGroup record where UserID is say 1.

Please supply L2Q code if possible

Malcolm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could express that as:

```
var query = db.Groups.Where(x => !db.UserGroups
                                    .Any(y => y.UserId == 1 && 
                                              y.GroupId == x.GroupId));
```

... assuming I've understood you correctly.

Comment: I'm guessing that `UserId` is in `UserGroups`, not `Groups`.

Comment: No that does not work in LinqPad. I want to get all groups for a user that the user does not have already. Is that better explanation.

Comment: @Malcolm: Try this updated version. It would really help if you could post what the columns are etc so I don't have to guess. Likewise I'm using a fairly non-OO approach, because I don't know what associations you've set up.

Comment: How do i project that statement into a POCO object called Group same properties as datacontext

Comment: @Malcolm: Not really sure what you mean... the result will be a sequence of `Group` objects... you can call `ToList` to create a list of them. It's just normal LINQ...